# udp listener receives packets from two different source port?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, udp, port

There is something makes me really confused.

I have a homework to do, sir simply wants a sender_udp.py and listener_udp.py.

But he desires something that i really cannot understand.

He says,

> Blockquote

udp_receiver.py should listen on the local loopback (127.0.0.1) port # 5444 and print out the message that it receives on the port. It should print out the sender address and the sender port number (if possible). The udp_sender.py should send to the local loopback (127.0.0.1) your first name from port number 5566 and your last name from port 5567.

> Blockquote

I wrote the sender and receiver, but receiver does not receive packets at all.

here is the receiver code:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 5444)
print(sys.stderr, 'starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)
sock.bind(server_address)


while True:
    print(sys.stderr, '\nwaiting to receive message')
    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)

    print(sys.stderr, 'received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address))
    print(sys.stderr, data)
```

and sender code

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
messageName = 'aaaaa'
messageSurname = 'bbbb'

try:

    # Send data
    print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % messageName)
    sent = sock.sendto(messageName.encode('utf-8'),('localhost', 5566))

    print(sys.stderr, 'sending "%s"' % messageSurname)
    sent = sock.sendto(messageSurname.encode('utf-8'),('localhost', 5567))



finally:
    print(sys.stderr, 'closing socket')
    sock.close()
```

Actually, i know with this code, it is not possible to send packets to 5444, client side sends packet to different port; and there is no listener at those ports.
I cannot understand what he means with this problem, Maybe he asked us to assign different source ports to each packet? Then, is there any way to do it with python, i could not find any solution?

Any help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code should be looking something like this:

Receiver:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_address = ('localhost', 5444)
sock.bind(server_address)
print('starting up on %s port %s' % server_address)

while True:
    print('\nwaiting to receive message')

    data, address = sock.recvfrom(4096)
    print('received %s bytes from %s' % (len(data), address))
    print(data)`enter code here`
```

Sender:

```
import socket
import sys

# Create a UDP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
messageName = 'aaaaa'
messageSurname = 'bbbb'

try:
    # Send data
    print('sending "%s"' % messageName)
    sock.sendto(messageName.encode('utf-8'),('localhost', 5444))

    print('sending "%s"' % messageSurname)
    sock.sendto(messageSurname.encode('utf-8'),('localhost', 5444))
finally:
    print('closing socket')
    sock.close()
```

Make sure when sending packets, to send to receiver's ip address AND port.
So if receiver is listening on port 5444, send to that port.